# Command line arguments for msiexec break on PowerShell if they contain space

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, installshield, windows-installer

I'm trying to set a public property in an InstallShield installer with a value containing space. While running the MSI installer, I'm using below command on PowerShell prompt. Since the value contains a space so I used double quotes to pass the value

```
msiexec -i "myinstaller.msi" MYDIRPATH="C:\new folder\data.txt"
```

It breaks the command as the argument value **C:\new folder\data.txt** has a space in the string **new folder**. It results in showing up below error prompt of msiexec:

> [image]

It suggests that arguments passed to the msiexec command has some problem.

But if I execute the same command on Windows default command prompt then it runs fine:

[image]

Few other options that I've tried to make things work on PowerShell prompt are as below:

1. Using single quote in place of double quotes
2. Using a back tick (`) character before space in the argument as per [this](https://superuser.com/a/881029/374397) answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Try with this**

```
msiexec -i "myinstaller.msi" MYDIRPATH=`"C:\new folder\data.txt`"
```

The escape character in PowerShell is the grave-accent(`).

Comment: Horrible! Not in my dreams I would have been able to imagine that. Thanks a ton for helping. I got some more details [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/47811/what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell) for reference.

Answer (score 9):

Note:

- This answer addresses *direct, but asynchronous* invocation of `msiexec` from PowerShell, as in the question. If you want **synchronous** invocation, use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with the `-Wait` switch, as shown in [Kyle 74's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57190814/45375), which also avoids the quoting problems by passing the arguments as a *single string* with *embedded quoting*.
- Additionally, if you add the `-PassThru` switch, you can obtain a process-information object that allows you to query `msiexec`'s **exit code** later:

```sh
# Invoke msiexec and wait for its completion, then
# return a process-info object that contains msiexec's exit code.
$process = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru msiexec '-i "myinstaller.msi" MYDIRPATH="C:\new folder\data.txt"'
$process.ExitCode
```

- Note: There's a **simple trick that can make even *direct* invocation of `msiexec` *synchronous***: pipe the call to a cmdlet, such as `Wait-Process`
  (`msiexec ... | Wait-Process`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69096536/45375) for more information.

---

To complement [Marko Tica's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499001/45375):

**Calling *external programs*** in PowerShell is notoriously difficult, because **PowerShell**, after having done its *own* parsing first, of necessity ***rebuilds* the command line that is actually invoked *behind the scenes* in terms of quoting**, and it's far from obvious what rules are applied.

- Note:

  - While the re-quoting PowerShell performs behind the scenes in this particular case is defensible (see bottom section), it isn't what `msiexec.exe` requires.
  - Up to at least PowerShell 7.1, some of the re-quoting is downright *broken*, and the problems, along with a potential upcoming (partial) fix, are summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).
  - Marko Tica's workaround *relies* on this broken behavior, and with the for now *experimental* feature that attempts to fix the broken behavior (`PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`, available since Core 7.2.0-preview.5), the *workaround would break*.  Sadly, it looks like then simply *omitting* the workaround won't work either, because it was decided *not* to include accommodations for the special quoting requirements of high-profile CLIs such as `msiexec` - see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143#issuecomment-833568832).

To help with this problem, **PSv3+** offers **[`--%`, the *stop-parsing symbol*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing)**, which is the perfect fit here, given that **the command line contains *no* references to *PowerShell variables or expressions***: `--%` **passes the rest of the command line *as-is* to the external utility, save for potential expansion of `%...%`-style environment variables**:

```sh
# Everything after --% is passed as-is.
msiexec --% -i "myinstaller.msi" MYDIRPATH="C:\new folder\data.txt"
```

---

**If you *do* need to *include the values of PowerShell variables or expressions* in your `msiexec` call**, the safest option is to **call via `cmd /c` with a single argument containing the *entire command line***; for quoting convenience, the following example uses an expandable *here-string* (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)).

```sh
$myPath = 'C:\new folder\data.txt'

# Let cmd.exe invoke msiexec, with the quoting as specified.
cmd /c @"
msiexec --% -i "myinstaller.msi" MYDIRPATH="$myPath"
"@
```

---

**If you don't mind installing a third-party module**, the **`ie` function** from the [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) (`Install-Module Native`) **obviates the need for any workarounds**: it fixes problems with arguments that have *embedded* `"` chars. as well as *empty-string* arguments and contains important accommodations for high-profile CLIs such as `msiexec` on Windows, *and* will continue to work as expected even with the `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` feature in effect:

```sh
# `ie` takes care of all necessary behind-the-scenes re-quoting.
ie msiexec -i "myinstaller.msi" MYDIRPATH="C:\new folder\data.txt"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

PowerShell translated
`MYDIRPATH="C:\new folder\data.txt"` into
`"MYDIRPATH=C:\new folder\data.txt"` behind the scenes - note how the *entire* token is now enclosed in `"..."`.

*Arguably*, these two forms should be considered *equivalent* by `msiexec`, but all bets are off in the anarchic world of Windows command-line argument parsing.

Comment: Cool! `msiexec --% -i "myinstaller.msi" MYDIRPATH="C:\new folder\data.txt"` also works. In fact this is a more cleaner solution than trying that magical back tick character as escape sequence.

Comment: @RBT: Indeed: because in your case you don't need PowerShell to interpret the command line at all, `--%` is simplest.

Comment: True. In fact, in reality I've got several command line arguments for `msiexec` which can have spaces in them.I showed only one command line argument just to ensure simplicity in my post. When there are several command-line arguments with a possibility of space in them, applying back tick escape sequence would become a nightmare.

Comment: If you are stuck with PowerShell 2.0 on older systems, you can use a command-line tool such as `showargs.exe` (see [Windows IT Pro - Running Executables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell)) to get a look at the _actual_ command line that PowerShell passes to an executable.

Comment: This answer solved my problem too. I was executing msiexec from Powershell with a path as a msi property. --% solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Wow I never knew that.  I wish one place had every single detail of powershell lol.  `echo hi | find --% "hi"`

Comment: @js2010 obviously there's a single place for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: @phuclv, the conceptual help topic you link to only explains PowerShell literals _in the context of native PowerShell commands_, so it doesn't apply to the issue at hand, which is about how PowerShell _invisibly rebuilds the command line behind the scenes when calling external programs_ on Windows (of necessity, to only use `"..."` quoting). Please see my update, which provides more background (including the link to said topic, among others), a `cmd /c` alternative, and a link to the `Native` module whose `ie` function shields users from all behind-the-scenes re-quoting problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to install a program in general with Powershell.

Here's an example from my own script:

```
start-process "c:\temp\SQLClient\sqlncli (x64).msi" -argumentlist "/qn IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES" -wait
```

Use `Start-Process "Path\to\file\file.msi or .exe" -argumentlist (Parameters) "-qn or whatever" -wait`.

Now **-wait** is important, if you have a script with a slew of programs being installed, the wait command, like piping to Out-Null, will force Powershell to wait until the program finishes installing before continuing forward.

Comment: Adding a link to the [Windows Installer PowerShell Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436779/129130) by [Heath Stewart](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/).