# How can I write/create a powershell script verbatim, from another powershell script?

Tags: powershell

The following code (at the bottom) produces one of the following outputs in the file

```
4/12/2019 = (get-date).AddDays(2).ToShortDateString();
4/13/2019 = (get-date).AddDays(2 + 1).ToShortDateString();
```

or if I haven't initialized the variable

```
 = (get-date).AddDays(2).ToShortDateString();
 = (get-date).AddDays(2 + 1).ToShortDateString();
```

This is the code block, I would like the parent ps1 file to write the child ps1 file verbatim.

```
$multiLineScript2 = @"

    $startDate2 = (get-date).AddDays($resultOfSubtraction).ToShortDateString();
    $endDate2 = (get-date).AddDays($resultOfSubtraction + 1).ToShortDateString();
"@

$multiLineScript2 | Out-File "c:\file2.ps1";
```

Comment: Use single quotes for the here string (not script block) to have the variables **NOT** expanded.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**:

To create a ***verbatim* multi-line string** (i.e., a string with *literal contents*), use **a *single-quoted* here-string**:

```
$multiLineScript2 = @'

    $startDate2 = (get-date).AddDays($resultOfSubtraction).ToShortDateString();
    $endDate2 = (get-date).AddDays($resultOfSubtraction + 1).ToShortDateString();
'@
```

Note the use of `@'` and `'@` as the delimiters.

**Use a *double-quoted* here-string only if *string expansion* (interpolation) is needed**; to *selectively suppress* expansion, **escape `$` chars. to be included *verbatim* as `` `$ ``**, as shown in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55612497/45375).

---

#### String Literals in PowerShell

[`Get-Help about_quoting rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) discusses the **types of string literals supported by PowerShell**:

- To get a **string with *literal* content** (no interpolation, what C# would call a **verbatim** string), use *single quotes*: `'...'`

  - To embed `'` chars. inside a `'...'` string, *double* them (`''`); all other chars. can be used as-is.
- To get an ***expandable* string** (string interpolation), i.e., a string in which variable references (e.g., `$var` or `${var}`) and expressions (e.g., `$($var.Name)`) can be embedded that are replaced with their values, use *double quotes*: `"..."`

  - To selectively ***suppress* expansion**, backtick-escape `$` chars.; e.g., to prevent `$var` from being interpolated (expanded to its value) inside a `"..."` string, use **`` `$var ``**; to embed a literal backtick, use ``` `` ```
  - For an overview of the rules of string expansion, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

Both fundamental types are also available as ***here-strings*** - in the forms `@'<newline>...<newline>'@` and `@"<newline>...<newline>"@` respectively (`<newline>` stands for an actual newline (line break)) - which **make defining *multi-line* strings easier**.

- **Important**:

  - Nothing (except whitespace) must follow the *opening* delimiter - `@'` or `@"` - on the same line - the string's content must be defined on the *following* lines.
  - The *closing* delimiter - `'@` or `"@` (matching the opening delimiter) - must be *at the very start of a line*.
  - Here-strings defined *in files* invariably use the newline format of their enclosing file (CRLF vs. LF), whereas *interactively* defined ones always use LF only.

Examples:

```
# Single-quoted: literal:
PS> 'I am $HOME'
I am $HOME

# Double-quoted: expandable
PS> "I am $HOME"
I am C:\Users\jdoe

# Here-strings:

# Literal
PS> @'
I am
  $HOME
'@
I am
  $HOME

# Expandable
PS> @"
I am
  $HOME
"@
I am
  C:\Users\jdoe
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this anywhere, but it appears every single variable in the script (string literal) has to be escaped with a tick like so. Instead of deleting the question I'll leave it up for a search hit.

```
$multiLineScript2 = @"

`$startDate2 = (get-date).AddDays($resultOfSubtraction).ToShortDateString();
`$endDate2 = (get-date).AddDays($resultOfSubtraction + 1).ToShortDateString();

"@
```

Comment: As @LotPings stated earlier, change your here string to use `@' '@` instead of `@" "@`. Then you don't need to escape variables.

Comment: @AdminOfThings It looks like OP want to expand some (`$resultOfSubtraction`), but not all variables.

Comment: As PetSerAl states, it seems that _selective_ suppression of expansion (interpolation) is the goal, which makes the phrase "every single variable in the script" confusing. The only good reason to use a double-quoted here-string (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) to begin with is if at least _some_ expansion is needed.