# Passing variable in parameter value in & operator - Powershell

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

I am trying to run below powershell script and passing `$project_name` in `--project` parameter but that is not accepting and not referring  to variable. How would i use that ?

```
$project_name = "webapp_deploy1"

$command = "C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe"

$param = @('partial-export','--project=$project_name','--password=deploy1','--directory=D:\Export Project','--ignore-history','--ignore-deployments','--ignore-tenants','--ignore-certificates','--ignore-machines')

& $command $param
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting (indent 4 spaces). 2) How do you know your command line is not working? Do you get an error? (Remember: We can't see your screen.)

Comment: I am getting below error

Octopus.Migrator.exe : The following projects were not found: '$project_name'
At line:7 char:1
+ & $command $param
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The following p...'$project_name':String) [], RemoteExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: For an overview of string literals and string expansion in PowerShell, see the bottom  section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use single quotes if you want variables to be expanded. use `"`

```
"--project=$project_name"
```

Comment: The `"` characters shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Actually, I don't think powershell normally interprets variables when it looks like a parameter, unless there's a colon.

Comment: Not sure why you say that, but it's not correct. I just tested again with my `showargs.exe` utility (it outputs the actual command line that PowerShell passes to it), and `--param=$arg` (where `$arg` contains a string) works just fine. If `$arg` contains spaces, PowerShell quotes the argument.

Comment: Correct, @Bill_Stewart, but do note that the OP defines the parameter as a _string_ as part of an _array_, where quoting is indeed needed.

Comment: @js2010: The problem only occurs with a _single_ leading `-` followed by a letter; Try `Write-Output --project-name=$HOME`, and you'll see that it works fine.

Comment: I might have been thinking of start-process.

Comment: My initial comment on this answer is related specifically to this answer.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: That's unfortunate, because taken _in isolation, as a stand-alone statement_ - the surrounding `"..."` are clearly necessary. _In the context of  answering the question_, they are _also_ necessary, as explained in my previous comment. If your comment was meant to point out that _as a direct command argument_ something like `--project=$project_name` doesn't require double-quoting: it lacks that important qualification.

Comment: @mklement0: I didn't think this was confusing. My comment clarified. Not sure what else I can say...

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, your original comment talked about a scenario different from the OP's - direct argument passing vs. the pass-arguments-by-array from the question - without explaining that context switch.
Your follow-up comment built on that unspoken context switch and discussed a specific scenario in response to js2010's assertion.
My comment was meant to highlight how different things were being talked about without proper framing, and provided that framing.
I think there's now enough information in this exchange to avoid confusing future readers.

Comment: Sure, glad you think so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you could run it this way.

```
$project_name = 'webapp_deploy1'
& "C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe" partial_export --project="$project_name" --password=deploy1 --directory='D:\Export Project' --ignore-history --ignore-deployments --ignore-tenants --ignore-certificates --ignore-machines
```

Comment: I am able to run this and it works as well but i want to pass variable in --project=$project_name instead of providing actual project name (Web_deploy1)

Comment: Ok, I changed it.

Comment: This works

$project_name = "webapp_deploy1"

& "C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe" partial-export --project="$project_name" --password=deploy1 --directory='D:\Export Project' --ignore-history --ignore-deployments --ignore-tenants --ignore-certificates --ignore-machines