# Encoding problem when creating a txt-file for outlook signatures that contains special characters, using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, streamwriter

I'm having some issues with a powershell script that creates signatures for Microsoft Outlook. I'm not very familiar with powershell and are attempting to modify an existing script. The problem I have is the encoding in the txt-file for unformatted mails. I'm in Sweden, so it needs to be able to use swedish characters (åäö). The txt-file that the script outputs do contain proper åäö, but when the signature is opened in Outlook, those characters becomes problematic, ä is shown as Ã¤, ö as Ã¶ and so on. 
After a little bit of googling, it seems that Outlook use Windows-1252, but I can't get powershell to output to that encoding.

This is the script as it looks right now;

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$FolderLocation\test.txt"
$stream.WriteLine("--- OBS TEST ---")
$stream.WriteLine("Med vänlig hälsning")

$stream.WriteLine(""+$strName+"")

$stream.WriteLine(""+$strTitle+"")
$stream.WriteLine("")

$stream.WriteLine(""+$strCompany+"")

$stream.WriteLine(""+$strStreet+"")

$stream.WriteLine(""+$strPostCode+" "+$strCity+"")

$stream.WriteLine("")

if($strPhone){$stream.WriteLine("Telefon:    " + $strPhone+"")}
if($strMobile){$stream.WriteLine("Mobil:      " + $strMobile+"")}
$stream.WriteLine("")

$stream.WriteLine("E-post:     "+ $strEmail+"")

$stream.WriteLine("Hemsida:    "+ $strWebsite+"")

$stream.close()
```

The file that this outputs looks perfectly ok when opened in notepad.

I tried this to re-encode the output file into various encoding, but no success;

```
get-content -path $FolderLocation\test.txt | out-file -filePath $FolderLocation\$strName.txt -encoding UTF8
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you try `$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$FolderLocation\test.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with your `StreamWriter` approach, heed [Theo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) advice and **explicitly specify the desired Windows-1252 encoding during stream creation**:

```
$stream = [IO.StreamWriter]::new(
     "$FolderLocation\test.txt",          # file path
     $false,                              # do not append, create a new file
     [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)   # character encoding
)
```

However, given how cumbersome the piecemeal writing of lines is, I suggest switching to a **single, expandable [here-string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375), which can you pipe as a whole to `Set-Content`**:

```
@"
--- OBS TEST ---
Med vänlig hälsning
$strName
$strTitle

$strCompany
$strStreet
$strPostCode $strCity

$(
  $lines = $(if ($strPhone)  { "Telefon:    " + $strPhone  }),
           $(if ($strMobile) { "Mobil:      " + $strMobile }),
           ''
  $lines -ne $null -join [Environment]::NewLine
)
E-post:     $strEmail

Hemsida:    $strWebsite
"@ | Set-Content $FolderLocation\$strName.txt  # See note re PowerShell *Core*
```

In *Windows PowerShell*, `Set-Content` defaults to the system's active ANSI code page, assumed to be Windows-1252.

In PowerShell *Core*, however, which consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8, you'll have to specify the encoding explicitly:

```
Set-Content -Encoding ([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)) $FolderLocation\$strName.txt
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Penguin616.

Answer (score -1):

Add-content instead of writeline should work.  Add-Content uses Windows-1252 encoding by default.  Swedish characters would be stored properly.

```
add-content test.txt "--- OBS TEST ---"
add-content test.txt "Med vänlig hälsning"

add-content test.txt ""+$strName+""

add-content test.txt ""+$strTitle+""
add-content test.txt ""

add-content test.txt ""+$strCompany+""

add-content test.txt ""+$strStreet+""

add-content test.txt ""+$strPostCode+" "+$strCity+""

add-content test.txt ""

if($strPhone){add-content test.txt "Telefon:    " + $strPhone+""}
if($strMobile){add-content test.txt "Mobil:      " + $strMobile+""}
add-content test.txt ""

add-content test.txt "E-post:     "+ $strEmail+""

add-content test.txt "Hemsida:    "+ $strWebsite+""
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24684546)

Comment: @Andreas Using add-content instead of .writeline() will encode in Windows-1252 and solve his problem.