# Bypass Powershell to run zsh command

Tags: powershell

In Powershell(pwsh)
Is it possible to "bypass" Powershell to not do anything and let the underlying shell do the work?

Sometime I need to call a command, that I copy from a site or other, that includes "\" and not "´" for line break - or other parameters, that Powershell try to interpolate.

Like:

```
 <Powershell Function> kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings \                                      
  --all-namespaces  \
  -o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNTS:subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name' | grep name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and let the underlying shell do the work?

PowerShell *is* a shell, so there is no underlying shell as such (in the sense that PowerShell needn't be launched from another shell).
However, there are **platform-specific *default* shells**: `cmd.exe` on Windows, and `/bin/sh` on Unix-like platforms.

> I need to call a command, that I copy from a site or other

**Before PowerShell went cross-platform, `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token) was introduced in Windows PowerShell v3, precisely to address your scenario.**

Given that *Windows* was the only supported platform at the time, **the behavior is focused on `cmd.exe`** - and even there it doesn't support `cmd.exe`'s line continuation via line-ending `^` chars.

More generally, while it tries to *emulate* `cmd.exe`'s behavior (e.g., by expanding `%`-enclosed tokens such as `%USERNAME%` as environment-variable references) without actually *delegating* to the latter, it doesn't do so *fully*.

In PowerShell *Core* (v6+) **`--%` is even supported on Unix-like platforms, but is of little utility there**, given that `cmd.exe` semantics are applied even there; notably, `'...'`-quoting is *not* supported.

(Note that PowerShell emulates one `/bin/sh` feature on Unix-like platforms, but only *without* use of 
`--%`: *globbing*, i.e. the expansion of unquoted tokens such as `*.txt` to matching file paths).

---

However, **you can call the platform-native shell *explicitly***, e.g, by passing the copied command string to `sh -c` on Unix-like platforms, **using a (verbatim) [here-string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375)** for the command string:

```
# Call the platform-native shell with a command crafted for it:
sh -c @'
  echo This line\
    keeps going\
    with --all-namespaces and\
    with -o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE'
'@
```

Unfortunately, **there's a catch**:

**Up to at least v7.2.x, PowerShell's handling of embedded `"` chars. in arguments passed to external programs (such as `sh`) is fundamentally broken**, requiring embedded `"` to be manually `\`-escaped:

```
# !! BROKEN
sh -c @'
  echo "high noon"
'@
```

To make this work, you have to `\`-escape *manually*:

```
# WORKAROUND
sh -c (@'
  echo "high noon"
'@ -replace '"', '\"')
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995) for background information.
In short: Backward-compatibility concerns prevent fixing the default behavior, but discussions are underway to at least allow *opting into* sane default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. I also don't know of any shell where this is possible, either, save for Ruby where you have the string literal operators making escapes much easier.

I would suggest that before sending strings to external commands, that you convert the [PowerShell escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7) to the target runtime escape sequences. This isn't a problem unique to PowerShell, but is easier to work with in other shells because there is more of an overlap of the special characters between other runtimes.