# SSM send-command with Powershell does not complete until background job finishes

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, ssm

I am using SSM send-command to start a Tomcat process on a Windows EC2 instance.

for example:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-id i-xxxx --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript"
   --parameters 'commands=["startup.bat"]'
```

This does indeed start Tomcat but I noticed that SSM command invocation itself is stuck in progress until I eventually shut Tomcat down, at which point it immediately succeeds.

My hunch is that something about the way SSM runs Powershell blocks on any spawned child processes (`start java ...` in the case of Tomcat).  I don't think this is unique to Tomcat or even Java, though.

Is there a way I can get Powershell to exit, leaving the child processes running in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **start an *independent* process in PowerShell** - one that stays alive even after the creating process terminates - use the **[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)** cmdlet:

```
Start-Process aws -ArgumentList @'
send-command --instance-id i-xxxx --document-name AWS-RunPowerShellScript --parameters commands=["startup.bat"]
'@
```

<sup>Note the use of a (literal) *here-string* (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) to make embedding quotes easier; see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for information about PowerShell string literals.</sup>

While `-ArgumentList` can accept an *array* of arguments, the way these are translated into a command line is broken as of PowerShell 7.0 (and will likely not get fixed due to backward compatibility concerns; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576)).

Therefore, it is **best to use a *single* argument with *embedded quoting***.

Note that you should **only use *double* quotes (`"`)** as argument delimiters when calling *external programs* (such as `aws` in this case).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] With *direct* invocation of an external program, you're free to use either quoting style, because PowerShell, when it rebuilds the command line behind the scenes, uses only `"` to quote arguments (if needed at all). In the case of `Start-Process`, the `-ArgumentList` value is passed through to a .NET API ([`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)), where no such translation is performed.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, although I still don't understand the difference because the `startup.bat` process itself terminates immediately because it starts some other background process.

Comment: That's interesting, @wrschneider. I know very little about `aws`, and I haven't yet tried to understand the particulars of your command: How is PowerShell invoked by the `aws ssm` command? Via its CLI with the `-Command` parameter? Perhaps the better solution is to send `Start-Process startup.bat`?

Comment: I see, @wrschneider. (a) does the command as currently shown in the answer work as intended? (b) What happens if you invoke `aws` directly, but pass `commands=["Start-Process startup.bat"]` instead of `commands=["startup.bat"]`?

Comment: Accepting this answer because it fixed my problem even though I'm still disappointed I don't understand the root cause