# Powershell variable replacement with Start-Process and ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, variables, quotes

I have this bit of powershell code that gets the FQDN and saves it to a variable...works great:

```
$FQDN=(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DNSHostName.ToLower()+"."+(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
```

LogWrite "[+] The system fully qualified hostname has been detected as: $FQDN"

However, when I go to insert the string of the FQDN variable, I can not get it to work correctly. I have tried back ticks, double and single quotes with no success:

```
Start-Process -Wait $OUTPATH64 -ArgumentList '/s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files\IBM\WinCollect\" LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_ENABLED=TRUE LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_PARAMETERS=""Component1.AgentDevice=DeviceWindowsLog&Component1.Action=create&Component1.LogSourceName=REPLACEME&Component1.LogSourceIdentifier=REPLACEME&Component1.Dest.Name=test.domain.com&Component1.Dest.Hostname=test.domain.com&Component1.Dest.Port=514&Component1.Dest.Protocol=TCP&Component1.Log.Security=true&Component1.Log.System=true&Component1.Log.Application=true&Component1.Log.DNS+Server=false&Component1.Log.File+Replication+Service=false&Component1.Log.Directory+Service=false&Component1.RemoteMachinePollInterval=3000&Component1.EventRateTuningProfile=Default+(Endpoint)&Component1.MinLogsToProcessPerPass=100&Component1.MaxLogsToProcessPerPass=150"""'
```

Where you see the "REPLACEME" string, I need that replaced with the $FQDN variable string. Whenever I use backticks `$FQDN` or  with double quotes"$FQDN" or even single quotes '$FQDN' I get the literal string of "$FQDN" and the snippet of code does not actually do the variable replacement.

What am I missing here? I have also even tried backticks double quotes `"$FQDN"`. I want the REPLACEME string to be replaced with something like the actual hostname + domain like hostname.domain.com or what is set in the $FQDN variable. The ArgumentList quotes need to stay the same as I can only get my command to work correctly by quoting the ArgumentList the way it is starting with a ' and ending with """'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Single*-quoted strings (`'...'`) in PowerShell are *verbatim* (literal) strings in PowerShell - by design, no expansion (interpolation) of embedded variable references or expression is performed.

To get the latter, you must use an *expandable* string, which is *double*-quoted (`"..."`); e.g.,
`"...SourceName=$FQDN&Component1... "`

Since your string contains *embedded* `"` characters, it is simplest to us the *here-string* variant of an expandable string (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`):

```
Start-Process -Wait $OUTPATH64 -ArgumentList @"
/s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files\IBM\WinCollect\" LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_ENABLED=TRUE LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_PARAMETERS=""Component1.AgentDevice=DeviceWindowsLog&Component1.Action=create&Component1.LogSourceName=$FQDN&Component1.LogSourceIdentifier=$FQDN&Component1.Dest.Name=test.domain.com&Component1.Dest.Hostname=test.domain.com&Component1.Dest.Port=514&Component1.Dest.Protocol=TCP&Component1.Log.Security=true&Component1.Log.System=true&Component1.Log.Application=true&Component1.Log.DNS+Server=false&Component1.Log.File+Replication+Service=false&Component1.Log.Directory+Service=false&Component1.RemoteMachinePollInterval=3000&Component1.EventRateTuningProfile=Default+(Endpoint)&Component1.MinLogsToProcessPerPass=100&Component1.MaxLogsToProcessPerPass=150"""
"@
```

If you used a regular double-quoted string (`"..."`), you'd have to escape the embedded `"` characters as `` `" `` (or `""`).

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for more information about PowerShell's string literals; the official help topic is [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules).

Comment: Thank you kindly. This worked out perfectly for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @user13458199; my pleasure. Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment:

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should work using back ticks:

```
Start-Process -Wait $OUTPATH64 -ArgumentList "/s /v /qn INSTALLDIR=`"C:\Program Files\IBM\WinCollect\`" LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_ENABLED=TRUE LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_PARAMETERS=`"Component1.AgentDevice=DeviceWindowsLog&Component1.Action=create&Component1.LogSourceName=$FQDN&Component1.LogSourceIdentifier=$FQDN&Component1.Dest.Name=test.domain.com&Component1.Dest.Hostname=test.domain.com&Component1.Dest.Port=514&Component1.Dest.Protocol=TCP&Component1.Log.Security=true&Component1.Log.System=true&Component1.Log.Application=true&Component1.Log.DNS+Server=false&Component1.Log.File+Replication+Service=false&Component1.Log.Directory+Service=false&Component1.RemoteMachinePollInterval=3000&Component1.EventRateTuningProfile=Default+(Endpoint)&Component1.MinLogsToProcessPerPass=100&Component1.MaxLogsToProcessPerPass=150`""
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I appreciate the feedback.