# How to create a JSON object with array in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am a newbie to Powershell and I couldn't find this on googling but how do I build a json structure with an array inside? Is it through a custom object? Have been a bit confused by the syntax that I have seen online and not sure what is the recommended way to do it. Eventually I need to be able to save it to a JSON file too.

```
json_ret = { 
             "a": 4, 
             "b": [ {"c" : 5, "d": "text", "e": "foo"}] 
           }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have JSON that you want to convert into a PowerShell object? Do you want to make an object in PowerShell that you can then turn into a JSON string? Are you just confused by JSON syntax?

Comment: I need a way to construct a JSON object in powershell and then save it to a file. The format above is an example. I am not clear on how to handle arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can build a json object through a PSCustomObject:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
  a = 4
  b = @([ordered]@{
    c = 5
    d = "text"
    e = "foo"
  })
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

- First we create PSObject using its type accelerator PSCustomObject.
- Then we define the root key and value "a", and we have to create an array inside "b".
- The `@()` statement creates an array, but we can't we create key-value pairs in array. So we use `@{}` to create hashtable. Before it `[ordered]` flag says the hashtable to keep the exact structure as we have created it.
- Then we define the array values, and after that close the internal array-hashtable.
- Now we end the PSCustomObject and pipe it `ConvertTo-Json`. Now you get a converted json.

**Footnotes**

- If you want to dump the json to a file, then use this:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
  a = 4
  b = @([ordered]@{
    c = 5
    d = "text"
    e = "foo"
  })
} | ConvertTo-Json |  Out-File "Filepath"
```

- If you want to save json to a variable:

```
$variable = ([PSCustomObject]@{
  a = 4
  b = @([ordered]@{
    c = 5
    d = "text"
    e = "foo"
  })
} | ConvertTo-Json)
```

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to create the JSON document *directly*, as a *string***, it's simplest to use a verbatim [here-string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375):

```
$json_ret = @'
{ 
  "a": 4, 
  "b": [ {"c" : 5, "d": "text", "e": "foo"}] 
}
'@
```

You can easily save that to a file with `$json_ret | Set-Content file.json`, for instance.

By contrast, **if you want to construct your data as an *object graph* first, to be converted to JSON with `ConvertTo-Json` late**r, see [Wasif_Hasan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62945522/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

**An *unquoted* `{ ... }` construct is a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)**, which is a *piece of PowerShell code* for later invocation on demand - and  the contents of your JSON document happen not to constitute valid PowerShell code, causing construction of the script block to fail.

Answer (score 2):

If using variables, then can create body including array like shown below, where $text is the variable. No need to user ConvertTo-Json and can easily copy the body from postman directly.

```
$text = "ABC"

# Post Body
$body = @"
{
        "name" = "$text",
        "description" = "$text",
    "myArray": [
        {
            "id": "2c91808680d3c34b0180dc81d78c21e9",
            "type": "myType",
            "name": "myName"
        }
    ]
}
"@
                
$body
```