# ProjectID variable syntax error in Powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax

Need help from the experts, $ProjectID will return valid but when I reference it in the code it comes back with an error.  If I list out the ProjectID manually works fine.  Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed.... Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're using a *single*-quoted here-string (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`), which, just like a regular single-quoted string, treats its content *verbatim*.

**In order to use *string interpolation* in (here-)strings - i.e. the ability to embed variable references and expressions and have them replaced with what they evaluate to  - use *double*-quoted (here-)strings**, a.k.a ***expandable* (here-)strings.**

For an overview of PowerShell's string literals, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375).

Applied to your case:

- Note the *double*-quoted here-string syntax, `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`
- Note that the variable reference, `$ProjectId` is also enclosed in `"..."` in order to satisfy the JSON syntax requirements.

```
$body = @"
[
  { "from": "",
    "op":0,
    "path": "/projectEntitlements",
    "value": {
      "projectref": {
        "id": "$ProjectId",
        "group": { "groupType": 3 }  
      }
    }
  }
]
"@
```