# Powershell inline commands on command line, quotation marks and new line

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, newline, quoting

I have a powershell script that takes a parameter from the command line.

The passed parameter is a string with new line characters but I cannot get it to work as I wish.

Example running from command line:

```
powershell.exe -command "& {& 'C:\My Scripts\Script.ps1' "Some Text`nWoo Hoo"}"
```

The script above is only passed the text **Some**.  If I use single quotes around the passed text the `n newline character is interpreted literally, not as a newline.

I'm sure there is some way to solve this!

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since your overall command string is (of necessity when calling from `cmd.exe`) double-quoted, you must *escape* the *embedded* double quotes as `\"` (even though *inside* PowerShell it is `` ` `` that serves as the escape character, as used in the embedded `` `n `` escape sequence):

```
# From cmd.exe
powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\My Scripts\Script.ps1' \"Some Text`nWoo Hoo\""
```

Also note that there's never a need to use `-Command "& { ... }"` when calling the PowerShell CLI - just `-Command "..."` is sufficient.

In your case, embedded *double*-quoting (`\"...\"`), i.e. use of an (escaped) [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) is a must in order to get interpolation of the `` `n `` escape sequence to an actual newline.
In cases where a *verbatim* (literal) string is sufficient, you can bypass the need to escape by using *single*-quoting (`'...'`).

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for more information about string literals in PowerShell.