# unexpected token in in expression or statement

Tags: powershell, escaping, quoting

I want to save a string with a skeletton and a few variables in there to use it later.

My string:

```
$moddeduserdata = ("{"Id":$userid,"Timestamp":"$timestamp","FirstName":"$numberout","LastName":"$numberout","CallId":"$numberout"}")
```

What I want is the following output:

```
{"Id":261,"Timestamp":"AAAAAAAJ1KM=","FirstName":"5503","LastName":"5503","CallId": "5503"}
```

so this results in the error:
"unexpected token"

I also tried with ' ' instead of " " but then it just saves the line without putting in my variables.

Comment: Are you looking for a hashtable? `@{Id=$userid;Timestamp=$timestamp;FirstName=$numberout;LastName=$numberout;CallId=$numberout}`

Comment: @flashbang hey there, no I need to have this in one-line but the varibles (like $userid) outwritten.

Comment: What's the *exact* string you want? And do you want the variables to be expanded?

Comment: @flashbang just updated the description

Comment: FYI, if you're trying to generate JSON - which that looks like - you can use `ConvertTo-Json` with a hashtable (like the above) as an argument. Use the `-Compress` switch if you want to remove the extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to *embed* verbatim `"` characters in a double-quoted string (`"..."`), so you must *escape* them as `` `" `` (`""` works too):

```
$moddeduserdata = "{`"Id`":$userid,`"Timestamp`":`"$timestamp`",`"FirstName`":`"$numberout`",`"LastName`":`"$numberout`",`"CallId`":`"$numberout`"}"
```

While single-quoted strings (`'...'`) allow you to embed `"` chars. as-is (no need for escaping), they do not perform the string interpolation ([expansion of embedded variable references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)) you need.

For more information about PowerShell string literals, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Or make an object then convert it to compressed json:

```
$userid,$timestamp,$numberout,$numberout,$numberout = echo 261 AAAAAAAJ1KM 5503 5503 5503
[pscustomobject]@{Id=$userid;Timestamp=$timestamp;FirstName=$numberout;
  LastName=$numberout;CallId=$numberout} | convertto-json -compress

{"Id":261,"Timestamp":"AAAAAAAJ1KM=","FirstName":"5503","LastName":"5503","CallId":"5503"}
```