# Add Column to Powershell Display Output

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm writing a script to audit the disk partition types in our virtual environment. I've got this code that produces the following output:

```
$vmName = "VM NAME"

$output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText {Get-Disk | select Number, @{name='Size (GB)';expr={[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}, PartitionStyle} -VM $vmName -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password

$output.ScriptOutput | FT -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
Number Size (GB) PartitionStyle
------- --------- --------------
      0       160 MBR
```

This alone is fine, however I also want to add the name of the VM as well, since this will be looping through thousands of VMs. I tried this, but it produced blank output for the ComputerName:

```
$vmName = "VM NAME"

$output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText {Get-Disk | select @{l="ComputerName";e={$vmName}}, Number, @{name='Size (GB)';expr={[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}, PartitionStyle} -VM $vmName -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password

$output.ScriptOutput | FT -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
ComputerName Number Size (GB) PartitionStyle
------------ ------ --------- --------------
                  0       160 MBR
```

Any ideas for how I can make this work?

As a bonus, any ideas for how I can add the actual name of the VM in there since the vSphere name may not be the actual name of the machine?

Comment: `FT -AutoSize` -> `FT *,@{Name='VMName';Expression={$vmName}} -AutoSize`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I changed the last line to this, but the output hasn't changed at all (still the same as output #1): "$output.ScriptOutput | FT *,@{Name='VMName';Expression={$vmName}} -AutoSize"

Comment: @iRon no luck with that either, still the same as Output 1

Comment: are you certain that the target system is not already added to your returned info? the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet adds `.PSComputerName` property that holds the name of the remote system. it is normally hidden ... and your `Invoke-VMScript` may be doing something similar.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Invoke-VMScript returns the columns "VM", "ExitCode", and "ScriptOutput". VM has the name of the VM, which is great. Now need to figure out how to combine that with ScriptOutput

Comment: `$output | Select vm, ExitCode, @{name='Size (GB)';expr={[int]($_.ScriptOutput.Size/1GB)}}`

Comment: @Daniel - i see that iRon & mklement0 have shown how to get that info. glad to see that you have a working solution! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- **[`Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText`](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/invoke-vmscript/#Default) accepts only a *string*** containing PowerShell commands, *not* a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{...}`).
- Since there is no separate parameter for passing *arguments* to the `-ScriptText` code, **the only way to include - invariably *stringified* - values from the *caller's* scope is to use *string interpolation***, as shown in the next section.

  - Notably, the usual *script-block-based* mechanism of employing the `$using:` scope in order to embed values from the caller does *not* work.
- **Passing a script-block literal `{ ... }` to `-ScriptText`** *technically* works, because on conversion to string the *verbatim* content between `{` and `}` is used, but is **best avoided, to avoid conceptual confusion**.

---

Note:

- Below is an explanation of your problem and a fix for *your original approach*.
- You can ***bypass* your problem** if you **add the calculated columns** via `select` ([`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)) ***on the caller's side*** (as hinted at by [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron)), using the `VM` property of the object output by `Invoke-VMScript`, which contains the remote computer name (which [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) helped discover):

  ```
  $vmName = "VM NAME"

  # Only run `Get-Disk` remotely, and run the `select` (`Select-Object`)
  # command *locally*:
  # Note the need to extract the actual script output via the .ScriptOutput
  # property and the use of the .VM property to get the computer name.
  $output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText { Get-Disk } -VM $vmName -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password |
    select -ExpandProperty ScriptOutput -Property VM |
      select @{l="ComputerName";e='VM'}, Number, @{name='Size (GB)';expr={[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}, PartitionStyle
  ```

**The command you're passing to `Invoke-VMScript` via `-ScriptText` is executed *on a different machine*, which knows nothing about your local `$vmName` variable.**

In [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_FAQ) commands such as [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command), the `$using:` scope would be the solution: `... | select @{l="ComputerName";e={$using:vmName}}, ...`

However, **`$using:` can only be used in *script blocks* (`{ ... }`)**.
While you are *trying* to pass a script block to [`Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText`](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/invoke-vmscript/#Default), it is actually converted to a *string* before it is submitted to the VM, because **`Invoke-VMScript`'s `-ScriptText` parameter is `[string]`-typed**.

Since `Invoke-VMScript` has no separate parameter for passing arguments from the caller's scope, **the only way to include values from the caller's scope is to use *string interpolation***:

```
$vmName = "VM NAME"

$output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText @"
  Get-Disk | 
    select @{ l="ComputerName"; e={ '$vmName' } }, 
           Number, 
           @{ name='Size (GB)'; expr={[int](`$_.Size/1GB)} },
           PartitionStyle
"@ -VM $vmName -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password
```

- Note the use of an *expandable here-string* (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`); **important**: the closing delimiter, `"@`, must be *at the very start of a line* (not even whitespace is permitted before it); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for more information about string literals in PowerShell.
- `$vmName` is now *expanded up front* in the caller's scope; to make the resulting `e={ ... }` script block syntactically valid, the expanded `$vmName` value must be enclosed in `'...'`.
- By contrast, the `$` in `$_`  must be _escaped - as `` `$ ``- since it must be *passed through* to the remote machine.

---

That said, **since you want to determine the actual computer name *on that remote computer*, you don't even need string interpolation**; use `$env:COMPUTERNAME`:

```
$vmName = "VM NAME"

$output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText @'
  Get-Disk | 
    select @{ l="ComputerName"; e={ $env:COMPUTERNAME } }, 
           Number, 
           @{ name='Size (GB)'; expr={[int]($_.Size/1GB)} },
           PartitionStyle
'@ -VM $vmName -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password
```

Note that in this case - since no string interpolation is needed - a *verbatim* (literal) here-string (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) is used, which also means that no escaping of pass-through `$` chars. is required.

When string interpolation *isn't* needed, you *could* actually pass the script text via a script block (`{ ... }`), which simplifies the syntax somewhat (a script block stringifies to its verbatim content between `{` and `}`), but since a *string* is ultimately passed, it is better to use one to begin with, for conceptual clarity.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I'm new to Powershell, so this was definitely a learning experience.

Comment: Much appreciated. Side question - any idea how I can select a specific column from that ScriptOutput?

Comment: @Daniel,  @iRon's comment shows an example of that: `Select @{name='Size (GB)';expr={[int]($_.ScriptOutput.Size/1GB)}}, ...`. For calculated properties that is fine, but it is cumbers some if you simply want a property as-is, without renaming it, say `.ScriptOutput.Number`; this is the reason why my problem-bypassing solution extracts the `ScriptOutput` values first, in an intermediate step.