# using "-Filter" and "-Like" with a variable

Tags: powershell, filter, exchange-server

I've got a hair pulling problem (I think)

Here's the code:
$dn="abc.com"

Get-Recipient -Filter {EmailAddresses -Like '$dn'}  -- didn't work
Get-Recipient -Filter {EmailAddresses -Like '*$dn*'}  -- didn't work
Get-Recipient -Filter {EmailAddresses -Like *'$dn'*}  -- didn't work
Get-Recipient -Filter {EmailAddresses -Like '*abc.com*'}  -- WORKS

How can I make it work with a variable, instead of a literal string value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (interpolating string, `"..."`):

```
Get-Recipient -Filter "EmailAddresses -Like '*$dn*'"
```

Note that [`Get-Recipient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-recipient)'s `-Filter` argument is a *string*, and that using a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) is not only unnecessary, but leads to conceptual confusion.

In fact, when a script block is passed, its *verbatim content* (except `{` and `}`) is used as the string value, so *no* expansion of variable references takes place.

- Note<sup>Thanks, [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings)</sup>: Unlike `Get-ADUser` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375)), `Get-Recipient` can *not* perform variable interpretation of its own, so an expandable string (`"..."`) is *always* needed if PowerShell variables or expressions other than `$null`, `$true` and `$false` are to be used in a filter, which must then be escaped as `` `$null ``, `` `$true `` and `` `$false ``.
  Otherwise, use *single*-quoting (verbatim strings, `'...'`), where no escaping (other than escaping embedded `'` as `''`) is needed  - see [Recipient filters in Exchange PowerShell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipient-filters?view=exchange-ps#custom-filters-using-the-filter-parameter) and [string literals in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375).

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell variable inside of single quotes is not expanded, so $dn is not `abc.com` but `$dn`, just replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: sorry, but that still gave me an empty return.

Comment: The real problem is the use of a script block (`{ ... }`), which binds to the `[string]`-typed `-Filter` parameter by its verbatim (unexpanded) content, irrespective of what that content is.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is put the wildcards inside a new variable and just use that.

```
$a = "123"
$b = "*$a*"
Get-<insert command with filter> -filter {name -like $b}
```

I'm sure there are a million better ways to do this depending on the kind of object you are working with. I'm sure I will get schooled here.

I mainly use this method when I am working within a confined dataset that I am familiar with. e.g. a list of locations