# Running PowerShell from another shell with Tee

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface

I'd like to learn to execute a PowerShell command from another shell or language, e.g. Python `os.system()`. What I want to achieve is the following:

1. Execute the PowerShell command
2. Tee the output to both the console and a file
3. Return the command exit code

I think this gives an idea of  what I would like to achieve, assuming to use cmd.exe as the caller environmnet:

```
powershell -NoProfile -command "& { cat foo.txt  | Tee-Object ps-log.txt; exit $LASTEXITCODE }"
echo %errorlevel%
```

There are some problems here. First, I cannot use quotations in the command, e.g. :

```
powershell -NoProfile -command "& { cat `"foo bar.txt`"  | Tee-Object ps-log.txt; exit $LASTEXITCODE }"
```

The `cat` argument seems to be passed unquoted and so `cat`  looks for a 'bar.txt' parameter.

I think `$LASTEXITCODE` is expanded soon, that is before `cat` is executed.

`&` is inconvenient to use, because it does not accept a single command line string including arguments. An alternative to `&` is `iex`, however I cannot use it from cmd.exe. In fact:

```
powershell  -NoProfile -command  {iex cat  foo.txt}
```

returns:

```
iex cat foo.txt
```

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `cmd.exe`, use the following (`-c` is short for `-Command`):

```
C:\>powershell -NoProfile -c "Get-Content \"foo bar.txt\" | Tee-Object ps-log.txt; exit -not $?"
```

- There's no reason to use `& { ... }` in a string passed to `-Command` - just use `...` instead.
- Escape *embedded* `"` chars. as `\"` (PowerShell (Core) 7+ also accepts `""`).

  - Alternatively, as [marsze's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67351613/45375) points out, you can use `'...'` (single-quoting) inside the `"..."` string passed to `-Command` / `-c`, assuming that no [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) is required.
- Since only *PowerShell-native* commands are involved in the command (on Windows, `cat` is simply an alias of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)), `$LASTEXITCODE` is *not* set, as it only reflects the exit code of *external programs*. Instead, the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) applies, which is a *Boolean* that indicates whether any errors were emitted by the commands in the most recently executed pipeline.

  - *Negating* this value with `-not` means that `$true` is converted to `$false` and `$false` to `$true`, and these values are converted to *integers* for the outside, with `$false` mapping to `0` and `$true` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works (btw there is a `}` leftover), but I am not sure about what's going on behind the scenes. I think that, given the command  `foo.exe argstring`, Windows cmd sends `argstring`  as is to  `foo.exe`, and it's up to the latter to decide how to parse the string. Software with Unix roots parses `\"` as a literal `"`. PowerShell is a bit weird, here,  because it extensively documents  its  backtick-escaping feature, but its own executable PowerShell.exe does not follow this convention. Please, correct me if my speculation is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, @antonio - fixed now. While it can be confusing, the PowerShell _CLI_ acts differently than regular PowerShell code in order to align with the most widely used convention for escaping `"` chars. on the command line on Windows. (The underlying architecture of argument-passing on Windows is really unfortunate.) However, conversely, when PowerShell parses arguments _to_ external programs fundamental problems still exist, although steps are finally being taken to address that - see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143).

Comment: @antonio: Another way of putting it: The _unescaped_ `"` have syntactic function _for the CLI only_, requiring `"` that are part of the _source code that PowerShell should execute after CLI parsing_ to be `\"`-escaped. That is, `\"` becomes just `"` when PowerShell evaluates the command string and then have syntactic function for _PowerShell_.  Note that if you're using PowerShell (Core), it is preferable to use `""` on  the command line, because `\"` can actually break `cmd.exe`'s syntax; e.g., `powershell -NoProfile -c " \"foo & bar\" "` fails, unlike `pwsh -NoProfile -c " ""foo & bar"" "`

Answer (score 4):

Powershell supports single quotes, which saved me in such situations quite a lot of times. The good thing about it: They are unambiguous and easy to read. But mind that variable expansion won't work inside single-quoted strings.

```
powershell -NoProfile -command "cat 'foo bar.txt' | tee ps-log.txt"
```

Apart from that, have a look at the useful advice in mklement0's answer.

Comment: Thank you, I realised this indeed but, while I could always expand a variable before sending it to PowerShell, the arguments string could have  single quotes. So I need to find an escaping mechanism: `\"it's foo\"` works; I can't find an equivalent  `\'it's foo\'` working.