# Powershell - Set-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace certain lines in a file that doesnt match the condition and then i need to write the output to a diff file [ I actually need the output to be redirected to the same file, but i dont know how to do it] and get the below error

Code -

```
   $fileName = E:\onlinecode\afarm_2106.txt
  $FileModified = @() 
 [System.IO.StreamReader]$afarmfile = [System.IO.File]::Open("E:\onlinecode\Btnbar64\a_farm.txt", 
 [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
while (-not $afarmfile.EndOfStream){
$line = $afarmfile.ReadLine()
     if ( $Line -like "*2104 Training Markets*" ) 
            {  
              $FileModified += $Line 
              # Write-Output $FileModified
             }
            else
            {         
             $FileModified += $Line -replace "2104","2106" -replace "21043","21062"
            
            }
      }
 $afarmfile.Close() 
 Set-Content -Path $filename -value $FileModified
```

Error -

```
 Set-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
 At line:19 char:19
+ Set-Content -Path $filename -value $FileModified
+                   ~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Any help to resolve the issue / Directly write to the same file would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks, yeah the quotes was the problem

Comment: @Theo agreed, I removed my comment. I'll just point out where the error is then. Seems like you forgot to add quotes to the `$fileName` variable hence why `Set-Content` is throwing that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [Theo's improved solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67728847/45375), but just to point out what the immediate problem was:

**The RHS of your `$fileName =`  assignment *lacked quoting***:

```
# WRONG: Lack of quoting of the RHS string value.
#        This *opens the file in a text editor* and assigns $null to $fileName
$fileName = E:\onlinecode\afarm_2106.txt
```

Unlike in shells such as `cmd.exe` or `bash`, **assigning *string* values to variables *requires quoting* in PowerShell**.

Since your path is a *literal* value, it's best to use *single*-quoting:

```
# OK - string must be *quoted*.
$fileName = 'E:\onlinecode\afarm_2106.txt'
```

<sup>See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's string literals.</sup>

Note that **the need for quoting strings applies to *all* forms of assignments**, including to *properties*, possibly as part of a hashtable or custom-object literal (e.g., `@{ foo = 'bar' }` or `[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar' }`.

---

**Background information**:

PowerShell has two fundamental [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), *argument mode* (like a shell) and *expression mode* (like a programming language).

It is the *first character* (on the RHS of `=`, in this case) that determines which mode is entered, and since your value started neither with `'`, `"`, `$`, `@`, `(`, `[`, nor `{`, *argument* mode was entered, and your - unquoted - file path was interpreted *as a command*.

PowerShell accepts a file path for execution even if the file *isn't itself executable*, in which case it asks the GUI shell to open the file, as if you had double-clicked it in File Explorer on Windows, for instance.

Therefore, an unquoted `.txt` file path will open in your system's default text editor, and this operation will (a) be asynchronous and (b) produce no output.

<sup>Conversely, if your file path needs quoting due to spaces and/or is based on variables, yet you do want to execute it as a command, use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); e.g. `& 'E:\online code\afarm_2106.txt'`</sup>

As a result, `$fileName` was assigned no value, which effectively made it `$null`.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, the "automation null" value is assigned, `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`, which, however, behaves like `$null` in most contexts.

See [GitHub issue #13465](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13465) for a discussion of when it does not, and why distinguishing the two via `-is [AutomationNull]` should therefore be supported.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `switch` ?

```
$fileIn  = 'E:\onlinecode\Btnbar64\a_farm.txt'
$fileOut = 'E:\onlinecode\afarm_2106.txt'  # or use the same filename of $fileIn to overwrite

# loop through the file line-by-line and capture the results in variable $fileModified
$fileModified = switch -Regex -File $fileIn {
    '2104 Training Markets' { 
        # don't change this line, just output unchanged
        $_
    }
    default {
        # output the line with certain strings replaced
        $_ -replace '2104','2106' -replace '21043','21062'
    }
}

$fileModified | Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Force
```

---

Instead of `switch -Regex -File $fileIn {..}` you could also do

```
switch -Wildcard -File $fileIn {..}
```

In that case, replace the condition to `'*2104 Training Markets*'`