# Restore-PowerAppEnvironment cmdlet is throwing an error '' not recognized as the name of a cmdlet "

Tags: .net, powershell, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, power-platform

So, I have been unsuccessfully trying to restore a PowerApp environment for a Dynamics 365 instance, using  Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell.
The example according to [MS docs for the command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/restore-powerappenvironment?view=pa-ps-latest#examples)
[Syntax and example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbHbW.png)

shows that you need to create a pscustomobject first and then run the cmdlet. While trying to create a pscustomobject, Powershell throws this error

```
d4aaa888-a96z-54dg-9999-6942069b6qe9 :The term 'd4aaa888-a96z-54dg-9999-6942069b6qe9' is not recognized as 
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again. 
At line:2 char:31
+         SourceEnvironmentId = c3aae985-d87c-49cb-8212-8624159a6ed8
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (    d4aaa888-a96z-54dg-9999-6942069b6qe9:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The backup [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/backup-powerappenvironment?view=pa-ps-latest) seems to work but, with restore I am running into all kinds of issues. Plus just trying to create the RestorePointDateTime throws a

`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression error`

Comment: Change `SourceEnvironmentId = c3aae985-d87c-49cb-8212-8624159a6ed8` to `SourceEnvironmentId = "c3aae985-d87c-49cb-8212-8624159a6ed8"`

Comment: Apparently wrapping the SourceEnvironmentID in "" seems to have solved the issue. The example on the docs seems to be weird.

Comment: In short: In PowerShell, assigning _strings_ to variables or properties (including as part of custom-object and hashtable literals) always requires _quoting_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67729013/45375).

Comment: As for the linked documentation page: I encourage you to provide feedback there.