# Powershell setting content in CSV, how to use variable

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

This is what I have (the addresses are hard coded but I want to use variables for dynamic):

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath $test -NoNewLine -Value (
  @'
From:
hardcodedAddress1
hardCodedZip1
'@ + (Get-Content -Raw test)
)
```

The code below doesn't work.

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath $test -NoNewLine -Value (
  @'
From:
$address1
$zip1
'@ + (Get-Content -Raw test)
)
```

Anyone know how to get it working with variables?
Edit1: $test is my path to a csv file

Comment: @AbrahamZinala sorry, thats my error when writing. Its just $test which has the path ending with .csv

Comment: You just need to change `@'...'@` to `@"..."@` to allow variable expansion.

Comment: The title says`Csv`, but what you apparently want is nothing like csv...

Comment: In short: Only `"..."` strings (double-quoted) perform string interpolation in PowerShell, not `'...'` strings (single-quoted) - this applies to the here-string variants too: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's _expandable strings_ (string interpolation) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell string literals in general.