# POWERSHELL Task Scheduler passing variables inside -Argument

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation, quoting, windows-task-scheduler

Good afternoon,
I am very new to Powershell and am trying to achieve the following:

1. Loop through a folder directory
2. Set the folder name as a variable
3. Create a Task
4. Pass the variable (declared in Step 2) as the required parameter for the -File being called in the Task Action

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC -Directory -Recurse |ForEach-Object {
   $FolderName = $_.name

   $taskName = 'My Powershell Task_' + $FolderName

   # Create Action
   $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument '-File "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1" -name "$FolderName"' 

   # Create Trigger
   $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12:35am

   # Create Settings
   $Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet

   # Create Task
   $Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings

   # Register Task
   Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -InputObject $Task -User 'username' -Password 'password'
   }
   ```

The tasks are created as desired, however, the problem is that inside the **$Action** step, instead of passing the folder name inside the $FolderName variable, it is simply passing $FolderName as a string (I hope that makes sense).

How can I correctly pass the folder name to the PowerShell script being called?

Comment: Swap the double and single quotes. As it is now, `$Foldername` is not expanded, but taken as literal text because the whole thing is between single quotes.` Try `"-File 'C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1' -name $FolderName" `

Comment: `'powershell.exe' -Argument "-File 'C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1' -name '$FolderName'"` PowerShell doesn't *interpret* nothing inside a **single** quoted string. Double quotes are required for that, so switch the order of quotes, or escape the double quotes inside double quotes. You also don't need to quote `$FolderName` given that it's of type *string*.

Comment: @Theo: for invocations from _outside_ PowerShell (such as from Task Scheduler) you actually cannot use `'...'`-quoting with _syntactic_ meaning - PowerShell will treat the `'` as a literal part of the file path passed to `-File` and fail.

Answer (score 2):

- Your immediate problem was to expect the reference to variable `$FolderName` to be *expanded* (interpolated) inside a *verbatim* PowerShell string literal, `'...'`:

  - **Only `"..."` strings (double-quoted) perform string interpolation in PowerShell**: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's *expandable strings* (interpolating strings) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell string literals in general.
- While *swapping* the use of quotation marks - using `"..."` for the outer quoting and `'...'` for the *embedded* quoting in order to get interpolation may *situationally* work - depending on the target program or API - it does *not* work in the context of Task Scheduler.

  - **For *command lines* in Task Scheduler** - and generally on Windows from outside PowerShell - you **must use `"..."` quoting for the *embedded* strings too**, which therefore requires *escaping* `"` as `` `" `` (`""` would work too).
  - The reason is that **PowerShell doesn't treat `'` characters as having *syntactic* function when its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) is called *from the outside***, such as from Task Scheduler, `cmd.exe`, or the Windows Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>). For instance, if the path passed to `-File` were `'C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1'`, the `'` chars. would be interpreted *as part of the path*.

Specifically:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument `
 "-File `"C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1`" -name `"$FolderName`""
```

Note that you could simplify the quoting with the use of an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings); the embedded `"` then do *not* require escaping:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument @"
 -File "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1" -name "$FolderName"
"@
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Especially the use of a here-string is worth the +1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Theo and Abraham Zinala.  Both suggested to swap the double and single quotes and that worked perfectly.

Comment: Do you mean `"-File 'C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1' -name '$FolderName'"`? I don't think that would work from _outside_ PowerShell, such as from Task Scheduler; from outside PowerShell, quotes that have _syntactic_ function on the command line must be _double_ quotes.

Comment: To put it differently: While your `New-ScheduledTaskAction` call will succeed with embedded `'...'` quoting, the actual later _invocation_ of the command line will fail.