# JQ query in powershell is not working with variable in SELECT

Tags: powershell, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

In Power shell i am trying to run ORacle Cloud CLI command and filtering it with JQ.
If i use hard coded values in JQ select it is working fine..but if i use a variable instead, i am not getting any data. Please help.

working with hard-coded value in select:

```
oci compute instance list-vnics --all --compartment-id xxxxx  --profile myprof |C:\myfiles\jq-win64.exe '.data[]|select(.\"hostname-label\"==\"test1\")'
```

Failing code witn a variable in Select:

```
oci compute instance list-vnics --all --compartment-id xxxxx  --profile myprof |C:\myfiles\jq-win64.exe '.data[]|select(.\"hostname-label\"==\"$host_name\")'
```

Comment: In short: Only `"..."` strings (double-quoted) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values) in PowerShell, not `'...'` strings (single-quoted): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's _expandable strings_ (interpolating strings) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell string literals in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell does not expand variables in single-quoted strings.

```
$ociResult = oci compute instance list-vnics --all --compartment-id xxxxx --profile myprof
$jqExpr = '.data[]|select(.\"hostname-label\"==\"' + $host_name + '\")'

$ociResult | C:\myfiles\jq-win64.exe $jqExpr
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.