# Command not working with variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting, syntax-error, powershell-7.2

I have looked at similar questions and not finding answers that apply here. I have also been reading and digging around on learn.microsoft.com. Apologies if this is answered before and I could not locate it.

A geolocation API with a CLI is not working when I feed it a variable in Powershell.

The command: (site, API key and IP are changed for this post)
`curl.exe 'https://api.xyz.com/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXX&ip=4.3.2.1'`

The script as I have it:

```
[string]$lookup = $Args[0]
echo $lookup
echo "$lookup"
curl.exe 'https://api.xyz.com/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXX&ip="$lookup"'
```

I run it from powershell with `geo 4.3.2.1`

At first I did not use the [string] variable type notation but after it was not working and I did some reading on learn.microsoft.com
I realized I wanted this treated as a string so I added that.

The echo statements are just me checking how the variable is being handled and will be removed from final script. Both of them display the IPv4 address properly.

I have tried the script originally with

```
curl.exe 'https://api.xyz.com/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXX&ip=$lookup'
```

then added the double quotes around variable. Neither work.

If I edit the line in the script, and put an IPv4 address in there and run it, it outputs properly, so I know it is not the API or the command for it, it is how the variable is being passed from powershell.

When the variable is used I get an error from the API.

I have tried this in older powershell, and today installed powershell 7.2 and get same result.

Comment: In short: Only `"..."` strings (double-quoted, called _expandable strings_) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values) in PowerShell, not `'...'` strings (single-quoted, called _verbatim strings_): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's _expandable strings_ and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's _string literals in general_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'https://api.xyz.com/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXX&ip=$lookup'
'https://api.xyz.com/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXX&ip="$lookup"'
```

Looks like you are passing it literally. Try double-quotes outside, single inside.

```
"https://api.xyz.com/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXX&ip='$lookup'"
```

Edit: Variable expansion in strings and here-strings

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/

Comment: You propably don't need inner quotes at all.

Comment: im blind, good catch!

Comment: This was it! I knew it had to be some syntax mistake on my part. I used double quotes around the url, no inside or single quotes and the script runs perfectly. thanks again!

Comment: Thank you also for the additional reading/learning for me to study