# Rename Object with Variable - Rename csv column with Variable

Tags: powershell, csv, objectname

I am importing and exporting csv files with powershell.
I am trying to rename a csv column to include the name of the current week.
I am recording the current week in a variable ReportWeek.
When the new csv is created, it is adding the text verbatim to the column name instead of using the variable value

`Import-Csv $file|  Select-Object Name,QA_Level,Team,@{Name= 'Wk + $ReportWeek Lines';Expression={$_.'Lines Typed'}} | Export-csv $pathtofiles\temp\Filename_temp.csv -NoTypeInformation`

This is the what the header is written as
Wk + $ReportWeek
Lines

I would like it to be
Wk 2
Lines

Comment: Single quotes prevent variable expansion. => `'Wk' + $ReportWeek + 'Lines'`

Comment: Swap the single quotes for double; string "*interpolation*" can only happen within double quotes, as single quotes print verbatim.

Comment: In short: Only `"..."` strings (double-quoted, called _expandable strings_) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values) in PowerShell, not `'...'` strings (single-quoted, called _verbatim strings_): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's _expandable strings_ and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's _string literals in general_.